# Can I pass CancellationToken as parameter in AspNetCore WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-core-webapi, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

As far as I know if I use `services.AddControllers()` or `services.AddMvc()`extension in my `Startup.cs` "MVC will automatically bind any `CancellationToken` parameters in an action method.

I have the following `TestController` and `TestService` as Transient service.

According to this informations, when the auto-binded `CancellationToken` `IsCancellationRequested` will the tokens that I have passed as parameters be also canceled?

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ITestService _testService;

    public TestController(ITestService testService)
    {
        _testService = testService;
    }

    [HttpGet, ActionName("Get")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _testService.GetAsync(cancellationToken);
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public async Task GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //I also send the cancellationToken as a parameter to external API calls
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have the exact same question, and the only solution that I came with is as you did, pass the cancellationToken as a parameter to every service. And they will cancel subsequent task or Linq to SQL.

But I wish there were a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

> when the auto-binded CancellationToken IsCancellationRequested will
> the tokens that I have passed as parameters be also canceled?

By injecting a CancellationToken into your action method, which will be automatically bound to the HttpContext.RequestAborted token for the request. After the request is cancelled by the user refreshing the browser or click the "stop" button, the original request is aborted with a TaskCancelledException which propagates back through the MVC filter pipeline, and back up the middleware pipeline. Then, You could check the value of IsCancellationRequested and exit the action gracefully. In this scenario, there is no need to transfer the CancellationToken as parameters.

If you want to Cancel an Async task, since, CancellationTokens are lightweight objects that are created by a CancellationTokenSource. When a CancellationTokenSource is cancelled, it notifies all the consumers of the CancellationToken. So, you could call the Cancel() method to cancel the task.

Check the following sample:

```
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        //cts.CancelAfter(5000);//Request Cancel after 5 seconds

        _logger.LogInformation("New Test start");
        var newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(state =>
        {
            int i = 1;
            var token = (System.Threading.CancellationToken)state;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                i++;
                if (i == 10)
                {
                    cts.Cancel(); //call the Cancel method to cancel.
                }
                _logger.LogInformation("thread running " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }, cts.Token, cts.Token);

        try
        {
            newTask.Wait(10000);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Catch:" + newTask.Status);
        }

        _logger.LogInformation("Test end");
```

More detail information about using CancellationToken, please check the following articles:

[Using CancellationTokens in ASP.NET Core MVC controllers](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/)

Comment: I read that article but I will try to explain. I mean I have 3 async method. First method is my Controller Action and calls Second and than Second calls Third. For example First method takes 5 seconds. Second method takes 5 seconds and Third method takes 10 seconds. I'm passing CancellationToken from first to second to third. If the user cancels the request at eleventh(11) second, does the third method keep working for another 9 seconds?